# The discrete distance is thiner then any distance

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The discret distance on a set $E$ is given by $d(x,y)=\begin{cases} 1,~x\neq y\\ 0,~ x=y\end{cases}$
and let an other distance $d'$ on $E$.

To prove that $d$ is thiner than $d'$ we prove that any open A related to $d'$ is open related to $d$.

$A$ is an open related to $d'$ iff $\forall x\in A, \exists r>0, B_d'(x,r)\subset A$

$B_d(x,r)=\begin{cases}\{x\},~ 0<r<1,\\
E,~ r\geq 1\end{cases}$

If $0<r<1$ then we are done $B_d(x,r)\subset B_{d'}(x,r)\subset A$, but how to do if $r\geq 1$?

Thank you

Comment: do you mean "than" or "then"?

Comment: Your notation is unusual. I have never seen the concept of a "thinner metric". The standard wording is "stronger metric":  $d$ is a stronger metric than $d'$ if every open subset of $E$ with respect to $d'$ is also open with respect to $d$. In other words, the topology generated by $d$ is finer than the topology generated by $d'$.

Answer (score 1):

That's a "there exists" quantifier. You've shown that $r=\frac12$ works. That's enough; you're done, and you don't need to worry about any other $r$. You have a ball centered at $x$ inside $A$, which is what you were looking for.

The discrete metric induces the discrete topology, in which *every* set is open.